# Is there a maximum number of rows allowed for this array? C++

Tags: c++, arrays, size, limit

(**edited** to correct a mistake and specify code is written for C++)

I am making a large array, `P_arr` of size

```
    int N = 30;
    float P_arr[27000][4];
```

with elements given by

```
    float ua_min = 0.0001, ua_max = 0.0075, us_min = 2, us_max = 100, g_min = 0.1, g_max = 0.8;

    float ua_start = ua_min + ua_min;
    float ua_end = ua_max - ua_max;
    float us_start = us_min + us_min;
    float us_end = us_max - us_max; 
    float g_start = g_min + g_min; 
    float g_end = g_max - g_max;

    float ua_stepSize = (ua_end - ua_start) / (N - 1);
    float us_stepSize = (us_end - us_start) / (N - 1);
    float g_stepSize = (g_end - g_start) / (N - 1);

    float ua_arr[3];
    float us_arr[3];
    float g_arr[3];

    ua_arr[0] = ua_start;
    us_arr[0] = us_start;
    g_arr[0] = g_start;

    for (int j = 1; j < N; j++)
    {
        ua_arr[j] = ua_arr[j - 1] + ua_stepSize;
        us_arr[j] = us_arr[j - 1] + us_stepSize;
        g_arr[j] = g_arr[j - 1] + g_stepSize;
    }

    int i = 0;
    for (int u = 0; u < N; u++)
    {
        for (int w = 0; w < N; w++)
        {
            for (int v = 0; v < N; v++)
            {
                P_arr[i][2] = g_arr[v];
                P_arr[i][1] = us_arr[w];
                P_arr[i][0] = ua_arr[u];
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

**such that the number of rows is always N ^ 3.**

Once I increase N > ~ 30, and I increase the size of `P_arr` accordingly, the code fails to write the `P_arr` and "exits with code: -1073741571."

Is there a length limit to the array I construct? How can I get around this to define larger arrays, say with N = 100?

**update**

`float(*P_arr)[4] = new float[42875][4];`
seems to increase the limit of N -> ~ 35 and row limit to N^3 = 42875. Is my dynamic allocation incorrect as it is imposing this limit?

Comment: Is this an automatic array? Stack frames have limited size, so you can't allocate very large local arrays. Make it static.

Comment: From the code snippets we cannot see if the array has storage class `auto` which may lead to a stack overflow. Please [edit] your question and show the complete code in a single code block to allow us to copy&paste and compile it, i.e. a [mre].

Comment: When you change `N`, do you change the size of `p_arr`?

Comment: @Barmar - I did think P_arr was static. Am I incorrect?

Comment: @Bodo - I've added the rest of the code.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - the question was edited for clarity. the number of rows is always changed to match N^3.

Comment: Instead of using a 2d array, prefer to use `std::vector` of a struct/class.  The struct will help ensure that the data for rows is on the same data cache line, avoiding cache reloads.

Comment: @Zachary It depends on where the declaration is located. If it's inside a function, it's local and automatic; if it's outside a function it's static. You can make a local variable static by adding the `static` qualifier to the declaration.

Comment: @Barmar - and adding static qualifier increases its limiting size? Adding static float(*P_arr)[4] = new float[42875][4]; doesn't seem to change the result.

Comment: Yes, then it's stored in the same memory used for global variables, which is almost unlimited.

Comment: @Barmar - Okay, I will look into this, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to change the result in this case.

Comment: Your code is still incomplete as there is no `main` function, and it shows statements that must be in a function. It is still not clear if your definition of `float P_arr[27000][4];` is inside a function or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, the maximum index is the maximum value for a `size_t` type.

The "maximum size" of an array is restricted by your system's memory limitations.  This depends on where you put the array.

### Array on Stack

The stack or local variable area, traditionally has a smaller amount of memory allocated.  The idea is that only parameters, small quanities of local variables and return addresses are stored on the stack.  This is usually a small set of stuff.

### Array on Heap

Build systems and the OS grant a program more dynamic memory area, a.k.a. heap.  Some designs are that the heap grows towards the stack.  Be careful here because an OS may have to swap out your program with another program, and that includes the memory area.

### Array on Static / Automatic / Global

There is another area that doesn't get much discussion, which is the static / automatic / global memory area.  For example, a `static` variable inside a function gets placed in this area, as well as global variables.  This area may be larger than the heap or smaller, depending on the build system and the operating system.

### Array on Operating System memory

Many operating systems have API to allocate memory and different types of memory.  You will need to look up the maximum capacity.  One maximum may be the RAM limit of your system.  Another would be the size of your hard drive (the OS may use virtual memory and swap to the hard drive).

### Array on Memory Mapped

Some operating systems support allocating memory directly on a file.  The operating system will manage the swapping from RAM to file for you.  The size limit for this is closer to the available space on your hard drive.

### Is the size necessary?

In the ancient days, most computers had very little memory.  Data processing and storage used tape drives, since more data could be stored in a file than in system memory.  Array processing was performed in smaller blocks or chunks.  Temporary files were create as necessary to hold interim results.

Do you really need to hold all that data in memory at once?
Can you break it up into smaller pieces?  Smaller pieces are easier for today's processors.  Align your data with the size of your processor's data cache or the loading page size.  No need to have data around that you are not using.

Answer (score 0):

> Once I increase N > ~ 30, the code fails

As `i` increments `N*N*N` times. `float P_arr[27000][4];` is only large enough for `N` up to 30.

For `N > 30`, use a larger `P_arr[]`,

```
#define SZ 100
int N = SZ;
float P_arr[SZ*SZ*SZ][4];
```

Comment: This does not work and results in the same outcome as described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

When you need large arrays - place them on the heap. Use pointers to array to simplify the access.

Example:

```
float (*large2DArray)[200000];
large2DArray = malloc(100000*sizeof(*large2DArray);


for(size_t row = 0; row < 100000; row++)
    for(size_t col = 0; col < 200000; col++)
        large2DArray[row][col] = (float)rand() / rand();
```

Comment: I am trying to apply this dynamic allocation method. When I try your code I have the error: "value of type "void*" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "float (*)"

Comment: @Zachary it meand that you compile C code using C++ compiler

Answer (score 0):

Arrays with automatic storage duration (any array defined inside a function without using `static` or `_Thread_local`) are usually implemented using a hardware stack. The default stack sizes are 8 MiB on macOS, 2 MiB on Linux, and 1 MiB on Microsoft Windows.<sup>1</sup> Thus, your code overruns the space set for the stack, and the program crashes.

Generally, when you need a large array, you should allocate space for it using `malloc` or a related routine:

```
float (*P_arr)[4] = malloc(N * N * N * sizeof *P_arr);
if (!P_arr)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error, unable allocate memory for P_arr in line %d.\n", __LINE__);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

… // Work with P_arr.

free(P_arr);
```

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> “MiB” stands for Mebibyte, 2<sup>20</sup> bytes = 1,048,576 bytes.

Comment: Okay, however when I try this I have the same issue as in an answer below:  I have the error: "value of type "void*" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "float (*)"

Comment: @Zachary: That is a C++ error message, so it indicates you are compiling using C++, not C.

Comment: This is my mistake. I am using a C++ compiler and mean to write the code in C++. I will update the question.

Answer (score -3):

Consider the following:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("INT_MIN: %d\n", INT_MIN);
    printf("INT_MAX: %d\n", INT_MAX);
    return 0;
}
```

On my machine I get:

```
$ gcc main.c; ./a.out;
INT_MIN: -2147483648
INT_MAX: 2147483647
```

As you can see `-2147483648 == -2^31` and `2147483647 == (2^31 - 1)`.

To increase your range you can use `long int`:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("LONG_MIN: %ld\n", LONG_MIN);
    printf("LONG_MAX: %ld\n", LONG_MAX);
    return 0;
}
```

My output is:

```
$ gcc main.c; ./a.out;
LONG_MIN: -9223372036854775808
LONG_MAX: 9223372036854775807
```

To explicitly set the bit width you can use `int32_t`, `int64_t` (and possibly `__int128_t`, in `stdint.h`.

Comment: Both are wrong. Learn about `size_t`